# DocuSign for Salesforce - Custom Button Code Email Subject and Messages for multiple recipients

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

We have multiple recipients in our template workflow and would like a different email subject and email message to each recipient.  I have a custom button code to put customize the subject and message for the initial recipient, but need help on how to add the different signers/roles.

Routing:
Order 1: Broker 1
Order 2: Client 2
Order 3: Broker 1

Here's the current code:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")}
//********* Option Declarations (Do not modify )*********// 
var RC = '';var RSL='';var RSRO='';var RROS='';var CCRM='';var CCTM='';var CCNM='';var CRCL=''; var CRL='';var OCO='';var DST='';var LA='';var CEM='';var CES='';var STB='';var SSB='';var SES='';var SEM='';var SRS='';var SCS ='';var RES='';
//*************************************************// 
// Modify individual options here: 
// Custom Email Message (default in config) 
CEM = 'Please review and complete group application for the above client. Thanks!{!Implementation__c.Sales_Representative__c}' 
// Custom Email Subject (default in config) 
CES = 'ACTION NEEDED: Sold Paperwork for {!Implementation__c.Account_Name__c}' 
//********* Page Callout (Do not modify) *********// 
window.location.href ="/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID={!Implementation__c.Id}&RC="+RC+"&RSL="+RSL+"&RSRO="+RSRO+"&RROS="+RROS+"&CCRM="+CCRM+"&CCTM="+CCTM+"&CRCL="+CRCL+"&CRL="+CRL+"&OCO="+OCO+"&DST="+DST+"&CCNM="+CCNM+"&LA="+LA+"&CEM="+CEM+"&CES="+CES+"&SRS="+SRS+"&STB="+STB+"&SSB="+SSB+"&SES="+SES+"&SEM="+SEM+"&SRS="+SRS+"&SCS="+SCS+"&RES="+RES;
//*******************************************//
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot change the email subject/body per recipient. DocuSign does allow you to add a note to a recipient that will show up in their EnvelopeActivation Email. This can be done with RecipientNote section in the CRL parameter.

> If you do not want to specify both First Name and Last
>   Name, omit the FirstName~ mapping and define the
>   LastName~ mapping. **Your custom list must have a
>   mapping for the Email. Role, RoutingOrder,
>   AccessCode, RecipientNote, SignNow and
>   SignInPersonName values are optional.**
>
> The other fields are strings and must not contain either ‘,’
>   (comma) or ‘;’ (semicolon), since those two characters
>   are used to parse the CRL string. Since commas and
>   semicolons could be used in the RecipientNote, you can
>   specify *COMMA* or *SEMI* to embed a ‘,’ or ‘;’ in the
>   note. ‘\n’ can be used to embed a carriage return in the
>   note.
>   Example: If RecipientNote~RecipientNote__c is:
>   “Hi_COMMA_\nThis is a wonderful opportunity_SEMI_
>   please sign.\nThank you.”
>   The note appears as:
>
> Hi,
>   This is a wonderful opportunity; please sign.
>   Thank you.

Hope this helps!